# UIBarButtonItem can't connect to @IBAction to unwind segue

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, unwind-segue

[image: Error]

As you can see in the picture, in the Interface Builder the bar button item appears to be connected to unwind segue method however on the left hand side the small circle beside the unwindSegue action doesn't appear to be connected (its not filled in black). On the right it shows the bar button item is connected.

How can i fix this? I tried searching around for answer to solve this issue using unwind segue but to no luck.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint inside the `unwindSegie` method to test if it is called?From my experience, for unwind segue,the small circle does not filled in black

Comment: Yes I've inserted a print statement inside before its not calling it

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. It turns out I have to unwind back to the UIViewController that holds the view controller that I came from.
For example, I have VC1 that has a container that can hold another VC2. From VC 2 a button push VC3 up the stack. To unwind I have to unwind back to VC1 since VC1 is the VC that is the parent view controller of VC2.